# Visual Studio 2019 build order is not working

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix

My solution structure is like this:

1. **WiX Installer**: depends on Project A and B
2. **Project A**: depends on Project B
3. **Project B**: no dependencies

It is configured like that in the build dependencies. The displayed build order (right click on the solution -> project build order) is the correct one (Project B -> Project A -> Installer). But for some reason when i try to rebuild the whole solution thats not the order in which Visual Studio actually tries to build the projects. It always starts with Project A which of course then fails cause of the missing dependency of Project B.

If i manually build the projects in the right order everything works.

In my .sln file projects are listed like this:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectA", ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj", "{B80B7A8F-0576-41FA-BD3D-B3C6F5F8D6E7}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ProjectB", "ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj", "{D127D2C1-0F13-41F1-B4A1-218BC53ABC40}"
EndProject
Project("{930C7802-8A8C-48F9-8165-68863BCCD9DD}") = "Installer", "Installer\Installer.wixproj", "{1D504782-E92A-4C60-9ADC-6067E7E301AA}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B80B7A8F-0576-41FA-BD3D-B3C6F5F8D6E7} = {B80B7A8F-0576-41FA-BD3D-B3C6F5F8D6E7}
        {D127D2C1-0F13-41F1-B4A1-218BC53ABC40} = {D127D2C1-0F13-41F1-B4A1-218BC53ABC40}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: How did you build the whole solution that this issue occurs? In my side, I run the whole solution, it builds with  the right order as you said. Can you tell us what steps you did lead to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usually**, the build order is saved in the solution file(`.sln` file) like this:

[image]

So when you use this, you should build the whole solution with that file. But

**However**, in vs IDE, when you build A single project, it can follow the specified build order, but in msbuild command line, `msbuild projectA.xxproj` does not build B first and then build A according to the specified dependencies. This is also unique to vs ides, although the build dependencies are stored in `xxx.sln` rather than individual `xxx.proj` files.

**Unless** the entire solution(`msbuild xxx.sln`) is built in MSBuild Command Line, it will be built sequentially.

This is the situation that generally causes this difference.

> But for some reason when i try to rebuild the whole solution thats not
>   the order in which Visual Studio actually tries to build the projects.

I wonder what you did caused this and if you build the whole solution(`xxx.sln` file), this issue will not happen. So I want to know which build format or what you did to your solution.

**Since** MSBuild cannot build `wixproj` file, so you should use VS IDE or [devenv xxx.sln /build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to build the whole solution.

**Suggestion**

As a suggestion, you could use **Project Reference** instead to specify build order which will set the order in every `xxx.proj` rather than `xxx.sln` file. This will be more reliable and safe.

**1)** Remove the build orders under **Project Dependencies**(Right-click on Solution)

**2)** Right-click on **WIX** project-->`References`-->`Add Reference`-->`Projects`-->Select `Project A` and `Project B`.

**3)** Right-click on Project A-->`References`-->`Add Reference`-->`Project`-->`Project B`.

**In addition**, if it does not help you, please share with us what you did to cause this issue and any steps which caused it so that it will help us troubleshoot your issue more quickly.

**Update 1**

Just hint from **Eric**, and thanks to him for sharing the solution and test result.

**Solution**

**First**, remove all the project dependencies and then re-add them, after that, it fixes the issue. It could be an issue to this project since it was migrated from old **VS2010**.

Comment: I edited my question and added the section of my .sln file. It looks like the dependencies of ProjectA did not get saved saved into the solution. The projects are already referencing each other like you suggested.

Comment: I maged to fix it by removing all dependencies and readding them again. I have no idea what caused the dependencies to be missing in the .sln file tho. Maybe some bug when migrating the project from an older Visual Studio Version. It was originally written with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to build my solution in Visual Studio. But when building it on Azure DevOps Pipelines with MSBuild, it built them in the wrong order; with my WiX `.wixproj` project being built before one of its dependencies.

My `.sln` file looked like this:

[image]

What I did to solve the problem, was to manually add more dependencies to this file:

[image]

So my advice is to look in your `.sln` file and add additional dependencies that you think would make sense.